# How can I implement four key shortcut in Qt like Vs-code in Qt?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I see vs-code can use `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+L`shortcut, So I think is there have a way that I can do like that In Qt framework.If Can?Can you provide sample code for me.
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to implement a function in your application where if you press Ctrl+K and then Ctrl+L then something happens? Or did I misunderstood your question? If this is what you want, then have a look at type `QKeySequence` in combination with `QShortcut` or `QAction`.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile Yes, You are right, I can do what will be happened when user press `Ctrl+K,Ctrl+L` follow your tips.